# Can people refer to me as an MD in my recommendation letter if I have already passed my professional exam but my degree is still in process?

Tags: recommendation-letter, medicine

This year I am applying to an big university's summer camp this year, and I am not really aware of how US Universities handle this situation. I am a Mexican "medical intern", I call myself like that because I know no better term to describe my degree, which would be literally translated as "In-Social Service Medical Doctor". I have already taken and passed my professional exam, but my degree is still in process, and probably (very likely) won't be ready at the submission of my papers.

If it were a Mexican institution I would just use "MPSS" (Medical Intern at Social Service by Spanish acronym). However medical intern seems like I have just finished medical school and I am at my Internship year (which it not the case, I have already finished it, thanks god).

The only question I have is: would it be recommended that my teachers to refer to me as INSTERT FULL NAME HERE M.D. or Dr. INTERT FULL NAME in my recommendation letters? if it is not, how could they call me in those letters?

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling to understand exactly the position you are applying for and don't know much about the medical field, but would expect your references to refer to you on a first name basis in the letter. This seems even more likely in the case where the degree status is in flux/unclear. At some point in the letter it should probably say something like

> Luis has completed their MPSS at University of Mexico, completed the internship year, and passed their professional exam. They have completed all the requirements for their doctorate in medicine and will be receiving the MD degree at the graduation ceremony in May.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. In Mexico, virtually every recommendation letter I've read refers to the person by full name with degree, if it the person does not have an academic degree, a C. (stands for citizen) is written before the name. Is this not the way you do things in the US?

Comment: I think the practice varies from field to field. In computer science, first name is standard. Other fields may be more formal.

Comment: @LuisE Don't use any titles or letters you have not officially earned in your own system. People in the US are very familiar that the "MD" degree itself can mean a wide range of levels of medical education, a descriptive paragraph like StrongBad recommends is going to explain a lot more than inventing letters (and in your case, you may never be an MD, even after you've completed your study, if that isnt the degree you are granted) and avoids any accusation of misleading, especially if someone happens to be familiar with medical education in Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, calling yourself an MD would imply and, in some places, possibly require, not only that you hold a degree, but that you also have a license from one of the State Boards as a physician. I'll guess you would have some risk using the term otherwise, even if another country recognizes you as a "Medical Doctor". In fact, many immigrants to the US holding such qualifications in their home countries can't work here as doctors (physicians) and some, unfortunately hold fairly low level positions.

There are people who work in research and hold the MD degree, but aren't licensed to practice medicine. I think they are careful to avoid getting confused with acting physicians, such as MD (Research), or some such.

But saying that you hold an MD degree from a Mexican university would be different from calling yourself an MD and listing it in your titles, I think. People would misunderstand.

On the other hand, "Dr." is ambiguous and refers to anyone holding a doctorate in any field I'm Dr. Buffy, for example, but my degree is in mathematics. But I wouldn't use even that title until the degree is formally awarded.

Comment: "In the US, calling yourself an MD would imply and, in some places, possibly require, not only that you hold a degree, but that you also have a license from one of the State Boards as a physician" - Do you have a citation for that or at least a particular example where that's true? Everywhere in the US I am aware of, the MD degree is separate from licensing, and for example I know MDs who chose to continue in research rather than medicine. They are not licensed as physicians, cannot practice medicine, but they don't lose their MD degree.

Comment: I didn't say or imply that they lose their degrees. I said that they are careful not to imply that they are "physicians" but researchers. The public generally thinks of a practicing physician when they see "MD" unless it is spelled out.

Comment: The context here is an application for some sort of professional development/conference, not the general public. Although the OP shouldn't use the MD title if they don't have it, I think you are wrong that calling yourself an MD necessarily implies you are a practicing physician and I don't think it's even relevant to the answer, so I'm a bit puzzled why it's there. MDs who are recently graduated students in the US are also MDs before they are licensed to practice medicine on their own, so it's especially wrong in a closer context to what is discussed here.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I thought it important to warn a foreign national how the use of a title might be perceived in the US. Medical doctors are very sensitive about their "status". Much more so than PhDs, for example. No one cares whether I'm called Dr. of course. But that isn't true for physicians.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write "calling yourself *a physician* would imply... you have a license from one of the State Boards", then?

Comment: I would write "completed medical training (MD) in Mexico". To the public writing MD or Dr. (in a clinical context) means "can function like a doctor I know or one on TV". Residents, for example, are MDs that may have no license or limited licenses depending on the state. Once finished residency to work as an attending physician in a state you must be licensed with that Board, which certifies that you have taken and passed all necessary qualifications. (Source = I am a practicing MD PhD physician)

Comment: @AzorAhai MD is, in theory, a broader term, as there are physicians and surgeons (an older but still observed).

Comment: @mac Fair. Perhaps Buffy should write "calling yourself a physician or surgeon"